# How to find the content-length of a readable stream in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stream

I need to know the content-length of a readable stream. How can I do it?

I know about `fs.stat` but I am developing an API that knowing the content-length from a readable stream would be much simpler.

Comment: An alternative way of measuring the stream length is suggested by @robertklep in this Answer[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807073/node-busboy-get-file-size/31809962#31809962]

Answer (score 8):

the idea behind the stream is that you start working on data before the source finishes. thus, you don't know the `content-length`.

if the underlying source is an HTTP object, then you could check `stream.headers['content-length']`, but even that is not ultimately reliable as the client or the server could have lied.

in short, you can't. personally, i'd rather just store it on disk temporarily.