# Node/Busboy: get file size

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, busboy

I used busboy module to parse multipart request with below coffeeScript code.
The problem is, sometimes, on 'data' handler called several times for the request including one file. 
That means I need to sum to each size to figure the whole size.
Besides the file object in the on 'file' handler seems not including size information.

How to get the whole size without calculating each part?

Thanks in advance-

```
busboy.on 'file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) ->
  filename = "#{Meteor.uuid()}.jpg"
  dir = "#{HomeDir()}/data/profile"
  saveTo = path.join dir, filename
  file.pipe fs.createWriteStream saveTo
   files.push
     filename: filename
     path: saveTo
     fileSize: data.length
  file.on 'data', (data) ->
    # this data handler called several times 
    files.push
      filename: filename
      path: saveTo
      fileSize: data.length    
  file.on 'end', ->
    console.log 'file finished'
```

Comment: Can't you just do `files.reduceRight( (v,o) => v+o.fileSize, 0)`?

Comment: that could be a good solution, but I thought I missed something huge flow or important API. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're already piping the stream to a file, you need to use something like [`stream-meter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-meter):

```
var meter = require('stream-meter');
...
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  ...
  var m = meter();
  file.pipe(m).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo)).on('finish', function() {
    files.push({
      filename : filename,
      path     : saveTo,
      fileSize : m.bytes,
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: My `m.bytes` comes in as 0 even though I know the file isn't 0 bytes in size

Comment: @Growler try checking for `error` events, it might be that an error occurs that prevents the file from being written (I _think_ that it will still trigger the `finish` event after such a thing)

Answer (score 6):

This is a very late response. I hope it'll help.

`request.headers['content-length']` will give you the entire file size. You don't need `busboy` for that. It is a part of the request object and can be accessed as follows:

```js
http.createServer(function(request, response) {

      /* request handling */

      console.log("File size:" + request.headers['content-length'] / 1024 + "KB");

      /* busboy code to parse file */

    }
```

An example which uses the header size info to track file transfer progress can be found at:
[NodeJS - file upload with progress bar using Core NodeJS and the original Node solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529013/nodejs-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-core-nodejs-and-the-original-node-s)

**EDIT:**

As noted by @Matthias Tylkowski, content-length is not same as file size.

My own code has also changed since then. I noticed that in the file up-loader that I've implemented using NODEJS, I've read file size directly using [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Getting_information_about_selected_file(s)) and passed it to the nodejs server.

Comment: The content-length is not the file size, as there is some overhead for marking the boundaries

Comment: @MatthiasTylkowski Thanks for noting. You're right. Content length is different from file size. Will edit the answer. However I think content-length will serve as an approximate value for calculating overall file transfer progress.

Comment: If the request contains several files - 'content-length' will show a sum of all files size + tiny overhead.
If the request is a form data - it might contain non-files fields. That also impacts content-length.

Comment: This value cannot be relied upon as an attacker can simple change the value of this header

Comment: What if you are passing multiple files in the request?

Comment: @MrOli3000 As mentioned in my edit, I'm reading file info using HTML5 API and passing filesize, name and other info in JSON format to the server. It doesn't matter if there is a single file or more files. 

For details on getting info of multiple files using HTML5 API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications#getting_information_about_selected_files

Answer (score 0):

```js
busboy.on('file', (name, file, info) =>{

  let fileSize = 0;

  file.on('data', (data) => {
    // count the bytes sent to the chunck
    fileSize += data.length;
    // ...
  })

  file.on('close', () => {

    req['file'] = {
      fieldname: name,
      encoding: info.encoding,
      mimetype: info.mimeType,
      originalname: info.filename.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_.]*/, ''),
      size: fileSize // total file size in bytes
    }
  })
})
```